# How to merge objects in php?

Tags: php, xml

I'm currently re-writing a class which handles xml files. 
Depending on the xml file and it's structure I sometimes need to merge objects.

Lets say once I have this:

```
<page name="a title"/>
```

And another time I have this:

```
<page name="a title">
  <permission>administrator</permission>
</page>
```

Before, I needed only the attributes from the "page" element. That's why a lot of my code expects an object containing only the attributes ($loadedXml->attributes()). 
Now there are xml files in which the

```
<permission>
```

element is required. 
I did manage to merge the objects (though not as I wanted) but I can't get to access one of them (most probably it's something I'm missing). 

To merge my objects I used this code:

```
(object) array_merge(
                     (array) $loadedXml->attributes(), 
                     (array) $loadedXml->children()
                    );
```

This is what I get from print_r():

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => a title ) 
    [permission]  => Array ( [0] => administrator ) 
)
```

So now my question is how to access the @attributes method and how to move the arrays from [@attributes] to the main object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of possible ways

```
$attr = '@attributes';
var_dump($obj->$attr);
```

To move the `@attribute` into property

```
foreach ($obj->$attr as $key=>$val)
{
  $obj->$key = $val;
}
unset($obj->$attr);
```